# Creating snow cover frequency map in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I would like to create a probability map from NDSI_Snow_Cover for a school project. I am VERY new to object-oriented programing and remote sensing data.

I used the code below, but I don't know how to deal with each image in the returned search individually (if I need to). My thoughts are to create an image of snow / no-snow for each image returned in the search. Then for a given pixel in all the snow/no-snow images, determine the number of times there was snow divided by the number of samples (excluding results where the pixel is masked).

Does that make any sense?

```
var MOD10A1_Terra = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD10A1");

// Setting date range, the month number, and the day number
var start = ee.Date('2000-1-01');
var end = ee.Date('2017-1-02');
var month = 1;           // The number of the starting month; Jan = 1
var numberOfMonths = 1;  // The number of the last month in search
var dayOfMonth = 1;       
var numberOfDays =1;

// Filtering and Sorting MOD10A1_Terra
// the variable filteredTerra can contain multiple images
var filteredTerra = ee.ImageCollection(MOD10A1_Terra)
//.filterBounds(region)
.filterDate(start, end)
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month,numberOfMonths,'month'))
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(dayOfMonth,numberOfDays,'day_of_month'))
.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover');

print('NDSI_Snow_Cover images returned from search parameters:', filteredTerra);
```

The code above as written will filter the image collection to 17 images. What I think I want to next is to assign each image returned by the code above to a variable.

For example:

```
var image1 = the first image from the image collection filteredTerra
var image2 = the second image from the image collection filteredTerra
var image3 = the second image from the image collection filteredTerra…and so on.
```

How would this be done in google-earth-engine?

Comment: Is you code returning a specific error?

Comment: The code I posted works without any errors. I updated my post above to clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the ImageCollection into a list, which allows you to access any of the list elements individually:

```js
var ni = filteredTerra.size(); 
var img_list = filteredTerra.toList(ni);

//For example, loop through images
for (var i = 0; i <= ni; i++) {
   var im = ee.Image(img_list.get(i));
...
```